# Using image transparency between Picture Boxes stores as Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, transparency

I am using c# and winForms to create an application that allows me to have 6 Picture Boxes (each with a different image) on top of one another. Each image has alot of white space so i am trying to use transparency to allow the user to toggle images on and off. When an image is toggled off, the parent/child of all the other images will be updated to allow the transparency to work.

I First created a custom class:

```
public class MyImageWrapper
{
    public MyImageWrapper Parent { get; set; }
    public PictureBox PictureBox { get; set; }

    public MyImageWrapper(PictureBox i, MyImageWrapper parent = null)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        PictureBox = i;
    }
}
```

Then I Created the Array:

```
MyImageWrapper[] pictureBoxArray = new MyImageWrapper[6];
```

This next code is a test to Check if transparency works:

```
pictureBox[0] = new MyImageWrapper(pictureBox1);
pictureBox[1] = new MyImageWrapper(pictureBox2);

pictureBox1.Image = (Image.FromFile(""+ Application.StartupPath +"../../../images/imageA.png"));
pictureBox2.Image = (Image.FromFile(""+ Application.StartupPath +"../../../images/imageB.png"));

pictureBoxArray[1].Parent = pictureBoxArray[0];
```

Unfortunately I do not receive any error messages so it seems to be working. However when I run the program Picture Box 2 is not a child of picture box 1 (and thus transparency does not work)

I have not gotten as far as setting the images to be turned on or off yet, I am still trying to sort out the transparency.

The problem specifically is this line:

```
pictureBoxArray[1].Parent = pictureBoxArray[0];
```

When testing I replaced the above line with:

```
pictureBox2.Parent = pictureBox1;
```

This does exactly the same thing (but works!). However the way my program needs to work later I cannot do it like this. I need to fix the Array version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you need to put:

```
pictureBoxArray[1].PictureBox.Parent = pictureBoxArray[0].PictureBox
```

?

The two lines:

```
pictureBoxArray[1].Parent = pictureBoxArray[0];

pictureBox2.Parent = pictureBox1;
```

You have put are not equivalent. In one you are assigning the parent of the **ImageWrapper** and in the other you are assigning the parent of the **PictureBox**.

I don't know if this is an error in how you have presented the code or in your program itself.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly right! I am still new to using classes and I do not fully understand how they work. Your solution solved the problem. Thanks for your help!